# Can an Android device  play ALAC and WAV files?

Tags: audio, 4.1-jelly-bean

I have a music library in iTunes with all files being ALAC or WAV format. I currently play them on an old iPod that supports both files types.

I will be getting a new phone device (replacing Symbian) and am looking at either Android or an iPhone with the capability of also being a music player. I really prefer going to an Android device but need to confirm that I can play both types of files on the Android device and would also be able to sync with my iTunes library.

Can anyone confirm I can make this work?

I really prefer not to buy an iPhone which I know will work. From what I have read it looks like apps like Poweramp and doubletwist might do the job. I am a bit of an audiophile and want to keep the files in lossless. If I had it to do over again I would not have used iTunes but it is what it is now.

Comment: The app suggestions part of your question is off-topic. Please read the [FAQ].

Comment: Thanks for the edit- I tried to add the audio tag but kept getting an error message about it being a new tag.  ?? First time on this site.

Comment: did you try VLC?

Answer (score 2):

I use Poweramp as my player on an S3 and it works fine for AAC, AIFF, FLAC, and apple lossless, even for FLAC HD files from HDTracks.  I simply use Android File Transfer to transfer music from my MAC to the S3.  The only problem I fine is static in the music, if I use the EQ or The Tone controls.  I am still trying to find an answer for that, but with those controls off, sound is fine.

Answer (score 0):

This often is not a question of the device, but of the player and codecs used. I cannot tell from my own experience, as I do not use that many formats (mostly I play MP3), but on the Play Store you can find audio players advertising this. Examples include:

- [Winamp](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nullsoft.winamp)
- [Rocket Music Player](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jrtstudio.AnotherMusicPlayer) (not advertizing it in the app description, but some users report it working)
- [NRG Player](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mrgreensoft.nrg.player)

and more. Just do a simple [Search for ALAC](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=alac&c=apps) on the Play Store.

Answer (score 0):

Where did you get your  ALAC or WAV format,you transfer it to the iTunes library or just purchase them on iTunes store. If you bought it on iTunes store, it may have DRM protection which prevent you playing on other devices.

Answer (score -1):

Best player ALAC/FLAC (today found):

**[andless](http://code.google.com/p/andless/)**

> This audio player can play lossless files (FLAC/APE/MPC/WV), or any
>   files directly supported in Android. Now supports Apple lossless files
>   (in M4A container) as well. CUE sheets and playlists are also
>   supported

(description from project website)